# iis web.config redirect certain domain/path to a new domain/samepath

Tags: redirect, iis, url-rewriting, web-config

I need to use web.config to setup a redirect for a certain path/folder to a new domain using the same original path/folder.

Ex:
If www.domain1.com/path2match1/* is detected then redirect to:
www.newdomain.com/path2match1/* (same path as matched on domain1)

ex:
current: www.domain1.com/path2match1/someFileOrFolders/somefile.html
redirect to: www.newdomain.com/path2match1/someFileOrFolders/somefile.html

Any help would greatly be appreciated

thanks

Answer (score 5):

I managed to find an answer for my question on my own! (Yay for me! haha)

Anyways,
Here's how to do what I was asking:

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="NAME" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url=".*" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="(.*)/FOLDER/(.*)" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" appendQueryString="false" url="http://DESTINATION-URL.TLD/FOLDERS/{C:2}" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

**Caution!  Adding multiple  or  tag set or placing this code in the wrong location will cause the site to generate internal server errors, making it unavailable for visitors until the additional tags are removed.**

- NAME can be anything, as long as it is unique
- /FOLDER/ is the folder you are redirecting from
- http://DESTINATION-URL.TLD/FOLDERS/ is where you are redirecting to.